# Install gazebo-1.9 stand-alone with ros-groovy on Ubuntu12.04

Tags: ros-groovy, gazebo-1.9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I intalled **ros-groovy** before, then installed **gazebo-1.9.5** according to [gazebo_ros_pkgs tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/Installing_gazebo_ros_Packages). But when I tried to execute command

```
rosrun gazebo_ros gazebo
```

or

```
rosrun gazebo_ros-1.9 gazebo
```

the result is

```
[rospack] Error: stack/package gazebo not found
```

or

```
[rospack] Error: stack/package gazebo-1.9 not found
```

.

***roscore*** and ***gazebo-1.9*** worked well when ran them one by one.
So please can someone help me find out what's the problem and where is wrong? Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3691/install-gazebo-1.9-stand-alone-with-ros-groovy-on-ubuntu12.04/) by [GumpFang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/429/gumpfang/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This looks like `gazebo_ros` is not s is not in your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` or not even installed
to verify that it is try this:

```
echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

and see if you can find the path to the `gazebo_ros` folder. As suggested by your link, if you are on `groovy` you need to install the `gazebo_ros` package from source, which is also described in the link you shared, try the steps in there again and let me know if that worked.

cheers

**EDIT**:
I just checked the installation guide for groovy and it seems to me that in the instructions it never actually switches to the `groovy-devel` branch but would only rename the `ros_gazebo_pkgs` folder to `groovy-devel`, so use the this command instead:

```
git clone https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs.git -b groovy-devel
```

(@OSRF, you could maybe update this in the wiki, if I'm not telling any wrong stuff here ;), I am still on my roadtrip and wasn't following the latest developments)

---

Originally posted by [ffurrer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/28/ffurrer/) with karma: 349 on 2013-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) on 2013-07-22**:
it is the same problem for hydro (although it is the master branch)
`git clone https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs.git hydro-devel`

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-07-22**:
Hey guys thanks for catching that git syntax error. I just fixed it for both the groovy and hydro instructions.

**Comment by [GumpFang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/429/gumpfang/) on 2013-07-24**:
Thanks for your reply. Sorry to give you feedback so late. I have reinstalled gazebo_ros from source just as described in the link. But there is still no gazebo_ros folder in the path returned by "echo $ROS_PACKAGE_ROS" which is "/opt/ros/groovy/share:/opt/ros/groovy/stack" on my machine. But I can find folder "gazebo_ros" in the path "catkin_ws/build/gazebo_ros_pkgs", which "catkin_ws" is my workspace folder for ros. I suspect whether I need to add a ROS_PACKAGE_PATH manully.

**Comment by [GumpFang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/429/gumpfang/) on 2013-07-24**:
BTW your suggestion about git commad works well. I am going to update wiki for it. Thank you

**Comment by [GumpFang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/429/gumpfang/) on 2013-07-25**:
Issue is solved. It's my mistake. I did not run commad ""echo "source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc"". Sorry for stupid mistake!